# Convergence in absence of DCT

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Can you give an example of a sequence of non-negative functions tending to zero pointwise such their integral tends to zero but there is no integrable function which bounds them?

Answer (score 0):

The following works
$$f_n=n1_{[0,1/n^2]} $$

Comment: I think this is a valid example, but it would improve the Answer to explain why there is no (upper) bounding function of the sequence that is integrable.